# PL/SQL accept input with single quotes.

Tags: plsql

I am trying to use the PL/SQL accept functionality to take in user input. However I want the user input to be able to accept single and or double quotes. The double quotes don't seem to be a problem, however the single quote is a problem. I have my code posted below, but I keep getting errors because it doesn't like the single quote. While I know in a practical situation, the user input would be taken in via a web front end and passed to the database, unfortunately this homework assignment is asking for PL/SQL only. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
Accept p_1 prompt 'Please enter the region name (CHILD_NAME):'

DECLARE
  --pragma execption_init 
  user_input REGION.CHILD_NAME%type := '&p_1';
  v_res number :=0;

BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER INPUT:');
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(user_input);
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MY OUTPUT:');

 /* select count(*) 
  into v_res
  from REGION where upper(CHILD_NAME) like upper(user_input);
  if v_res = 0 then
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(user_input ||' is not in the table.');
  else
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Need to build my logic here.');
  end if;
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');*/
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) `q`:

```
set serveroutput on
accept p_1 prompt 'Say something: '

declare
  v_something varchar2(32767) := q'[&p_1]';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('(v_something = ' || v_something || ')');
end;
/
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> @so52
Say something: 'foo [is] 'bar''
old   2:       v_something varchar2(32767) := q'[&p_1]';
new   2:       v_something varchar2(32767) := q'['foo [is] 'bar'']';
(v_something = 'foo [is] 'bar'')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```